# Take photo using camera in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a camera project and it can take pictures but when I press the take picture button then given an error.

The error was: Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

```
    private async void TakeAPhotoButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Test",
            SaveToAlbum = true,
        });

        if (file == null)
            return;

        await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            file.Dispose();
            return stream;
        }); ;

    }
```

This is my code. All times are given error this portion.

```
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Test",
            SaveToAlbum = true,
        });
```

This is my Main Page.XAML file. where I design UI.

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Camera Access In Xamarin forms"/>
        <Button Text="Take a Photo"    
                x:Name="takePhoto"    
                BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"    
                Clicked="TakeAPhotoButton_OnClicked"/>
        <Button Text="Pick a Photo"    
                x:Name="pickPhoto"    
                BackgroundColor="Blue"    
                Clicked="PickAPhotoButton_OnClicked"/>
        <Button Text="Take A Video"    
                x:Name="takeVideo"    
                BackgroundColor="Gray"    
                Clicked="TakeAVideoButton_OnClicked"/>
        <Button Text="Pick A Video"    
                x:Name="pickVideo"    
                BackgroundColor="Green"    
                Clicked="PickAVideoButton_OnClicked"/>
        <Image x:Name="image"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm using NuGet Package on my project.

```
Xam.Plugin.Media
```

I'm trying to follow their documentation. I don't know what is my problem
I'm following these links [Xamarin.Forms - Camera App](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-camera-app3/)
. and youtube video [Using Camera with Xamarin Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJYLrVNY2ak)

Comment: As I noted in your previous question, you are following a tutorial that is 4 years old.  The nuget package is 2 years old and has been deprecated in favor of MediaPicker.  I linked to a newer question that shows how to use that control.  Why are you ignoring all of that advice?

Comment: I couldn't find any newer answer. That's why old...

Comment: Can you share any latest articles?

Comment: Look at your previous question, there is a huge blue box at the top that says “This question already has an answer here:”. Follow that link.  Or Google “Xamarin mediapicker” and the very first result is the Microsoft doc on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can test Xamarin Essential function for this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android

Or if you want make your own custom camera screen, you can see this one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview?source=recommendations